# post method show error as soon ass change post into get working better in laravel routing

Tags: laravel, post

here is my route

```
Route::post('/posts', 'Cdesigination@index');
```

HTNL and input Field

```
<div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Name</label>

                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" data-validate="required" placeholder="Enter Name" />
                    </div>

                     <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Detail</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" name="detail" id="detail" placeholder="Enter Detail"></textarea> 
                    </div>
<input type="hidden" id="_token" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">


                    <div class="form-group col-sm-offset-3">
                        <button type="submit" onclick="postdata();" id="post" class="btn btn-success">Submit Now</button>

                    </div>
```

my controller file

```
  <?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use App\Http\Requests;
    use App\models\Designation as desig;
    class Cdesigination extends Controller
    {

        public function index()
        {

            return view('designation');
        }

    }
```

where is the error have trouble me get method working fine but post method show error as soon as change 
this route show following error

```
Route::post('/posts', 'Cdesigination@index');

MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 219:
```

as soon as change post to get like `Route::get('/posts', 'Cdesigination@index');`
 error not show working fine   tell me how solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your `<form>` has `method=""` that matches your route declaration

```
<form method="post">
```

for

```
Route::post('/posts', 'Cdesigination@index');
```

Or

```
<form method="get">
```

for

```
Route::get('/posts', 'Cdesigination@index');
```

Comment: i'm using ajax method is post   ajax function                                                                    function postdata(){
 
   var name=$('#name').val();
   var detail=$('#detail').val(); 
   var token=$('#_token').val();
    $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: '{{url("/posts")}}',
                    data: "name="+ name + "&detail="+ detail+"&_token="+ token ,
                    success: function(data){ 
 
                    }  });
}

Comment: Then it looks like ajax is not kicking in and your form is getting submitted after you click the button

Comment: i'm not using from have only input field and button post data through ajax